# String.Replace in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, replace

I would like to know why it is not working:

```
string filename = optionFileNameFormat; // "{year}-{month}-{day} {name}"
Dictionary<string, string> tagList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
tagList.Add("author",System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
tagList.Add("year" , "" + DateTime.Now.Year);
tagList.Add("month", "" + DateTime.Now.Month);
tagList.Add("day"  , "" + DateTime.Now.Day);

foreach (var property in tagList)
{
    filename.Replace(@"{" + property.Key + @"}", property.Value);
}
```

I don't have any error, but my string doesn't change.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There may be other problems as well, but what jumped out at me right away is that the `Replace()` function *does not change the string*. Instead, it returns a new string. Therefore, you need to assign the result of the function back to the original:

```
filename = filename.Replace(@"{" + property.Key + @"}", property.Value);
```

Comment: To elaborate: This is because strings are immutable, so if you *ever* call a method to change one, what actually happens is that the method returns the changed string and the original string is unmodified.

Answer (score 3):

The [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) method returns a new string. It doesn't change the original string.

> **Returns a new string** in which all occurrences of a specified Unicode
> character or String in the current string are replaced with another
> specified Unicode character or String

So, you should assign a new string or an existing one inside your `foreach` loop:

```
filename = filename.Replace(@"{" + property.Key + @"}", property.Value);
```

or

```
string newfilename = filename.Replace(@"{" + property.Key + @"}", property.Value);
```

And remember, in .NET, strings are *[immutable types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)*. You can't change them. Even if you think you change them, you create new string objects.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
foreach (var property in tagList)
{
    filename.Replace(@"{" + property.Key + @"}", property.Value);
}
```

just do the below change:

```
filename =  filename.Replace(@"{" + property.Key + @"}", property.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the completed code:

```
 string filename = optionFileNameFormat; // "{year}-{month}-{day} {name}"
 Dictionary<string, string> tagList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 tagList.Add("author",System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
 tagList.Add("year" , "" + DateTime.Now.Year);
 tagList.Add("month", "" + DateTime.Now.Month);
 tagList.Add("day"  , "" + DateTime.Now.Day);

 foreach (var property in tagList)
 {
     filename= filename.Replace(@"{" + property.Key + @"}", property.Value);
 }
```